# android menu Home item issue

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android launcher page on the menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317873/android-launcher-page-on-the-menu)

I'm running my android app on my droid x2 device. this app has a menu with some items, one of which is the Home (the screen that launches when the app starts).

the problem is that when I tap on the Home item it brings up a menu that says,

"complete action using"
com.motorola.programmenu
com.motorola.programmenu
about phone
accessibility setting
.
.
.
.
.

I don't know why it does that and how i can fix it.