# android launcher page on the menu

Tags: android, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I'm running my android app on my droid x2 device. this app has a menu with some items, one of which is the Home (the screen that launches when the app starts).

the problem is that when I tap on the Home item it brings up this menu,

[image]

I don't know why it does that and how i can fix it.

It works fine on the simulator, I'm gussing this is something that needs to be set up on the device.

I need to know if some has seen this menu before and if so what it is and when it shows up?

Comment: Can you show some code? I think the AndroidManifest.xml and the Home screen activity .java file may be of interest here.

Comment: Can you post the code that executes when you tap on the Home item?

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If you have further details to add, edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fix this issue by adding a new activity to my manifest file. so what I had for the launcher activity was

```
  <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Home" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and I also added the following activity which would act just as a normal activity and in my menu selection I used the action name of this new activity.

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Home" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.mywebsite.app.HOME" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```